# BufferedInputStream use cases in network Socket and File Reading?

Tags: java, sockets, file-io, bufferedinputstream

I have a few questions regarding the use of BufferedInputStream:

First I have heard that BufferedInputStream significantly increases performance if you are reading data byte by byte from especially HDDs.

1. Does it make a significant difference whether I use FileInputStream or BufferedInputStream if I am reading an entire file with say in 4098 bytes chuck?

   ```
   ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

       try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath)) {

           // Create some arbitrary buffer
           byte[] buffer = new byte[4098];

           int length;

           while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
               result.write(buffer, 0, length);
           }
       }

       return result.toByteArray();
   ```

   Would using BufferedInputStream prove significantly useful here?
2. In the same way, does BufferedInputStream only make a difference in sockets when reading byte by byte i.e. is it only useful for pre-loading the buffer to read byte by byte?

Comment: You anyway cannot use BufferedInputStream without an underlying Stream. Also 4096 or 8192 or x or y or z depends completely on the OS and filesystem. It's usually powers of 2. buffer size should be a multiple of the page size.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it make a significant difference whether I use FileInputStream or
>   BufferedInputStream if I am reading an entire file with say in 4098
>   bytes chunk?

A BufferedInputStream will probably make little difference in this example.  First, you already call FileInputStream.read with a 4098 byte buffer, which is going to fetch data in chunks of 4098 bytes anyways.  This is all the "buffered chunking" you need to reasonably fetch data from a disk file.

> In the same way, does BufferedInputStream only make a difference in
>   sockets when reading byte by byte i.e. is it only useful for
>   pre-loading the buffer to read byte by byte?

If you fetch one byte at a time (either from a socket or a file), wrapping the stream with BufferedInputStream will probably make a difference.  Even though the operating system is already buffering your reads inside the kernel, reading one byte a time causes a switch to kernel mode to get a single byte from the kernel's buffer for each call.  This is inefficient, and is a good reason for using BufferedInputStream.

Answer (score -1):

Non-buffered streams read data k bytes at a time(k being page size; OS can read only in multiples of OS page size and data can be read from disks in multiples of disk block size) from the OS cache(may or may not read from disk depends on if it's already in OS cache). Buffered streams on the other hand  reads in chunks of the buffer capacity. So, you save precious disk IO reads.The buffer capacity should be a multiple of the page size which instead should be a multiple of the disk block size.

Comment: Make up your mind. One byte at a time or more than one byte at a time. Not both at he same time.

Comment: I used one byte as I donot want to complicate by getting in the details of page size and block size; at the same time do not want to completely hide the actuals from the users.